# Prolog own merge function syntax error

Tags: prolog

I tried to write a method to merge two lists. However I get "Syntax error at/before line 4" in tuProlog with this code:

```
mymerge([], [], []).
mymerge(A, [], A).
mymerge([], A, A).
mymerge([HA|TA], B, [HA|R]) := mymerge(TA, B, R).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a minus sign you need, not an equals sign.

Try `:-`, not `:=`